# What is the right value for nav_host_fragment?

Tags: kotlin, navigation

First of all, I am totally noob on Android Studio so please bear over with me.
I tried to resolve an error with nav_host_fragment, but obviously did something wrong and I get an error at this file:

```
<resources>
    <item name="nav_host_fragment" type="id">"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"</item>
</resources>
```

What should I put instead of "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The `navHostFragment` should not be added inside `resource` tag.
The above code snippet is not correct.

Please thoroughly go through the document by clicking on below link and make changes to your code accordingly. This page also has a video which will help you even better.

Link:
[Get started with the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhostfragment)

If you still face challenge, then please post all files and elaborate you issue in more detail.